How to permanently delete in QGIS an Annotations Layer?
Using QGIS 3.38, I created a few text annotations using the toolbar. After deleting them, I can see in the Layer Styling panel, an empty layer called Annotations.

The message "No item selected" makes sense because well, there are no items to select, as all of them were deleted already.
Clicking on the toolbox Main Annotation Layer Properties button, this is the window that pops:

Here, we can confirm that there are zero items (annotations) in the layer.
Given the circumstances, how can I make it disappear from the Layer Styling panel? Or is this a kind of "permanent" style layer that cannot be removed and becomes active only when there are annotations?

If I understand well this presentation of annotation layer by North Road there are two kind of annotation layer :



The “main annotation layer” which is always drawn on the very top of
the map.) This main annotation layer is a special beast, and you won’t
see it listed alongside all the other layers in your project.



This seem to imply that the main annotation layer is indeed always present and cant be removed (you can always choose this annotation layer in the Layer Styling panel drop-down)

the "secondary annotation layers"

secondary annotation layers appear in the list of your project’s
layers. Just like any other map layer, you can toggle their
visibility, rename them, and even reposition them to control whether
the annotations show above or below particular layers in your map



These secondary annotation layers can be removed the same way as any other layer by selecting it in the layer panel and clicking the "Remove Layer" button or by right click on it and selecting "Remove Layer..."
So it seem you will always have at last one annotation layer (even an empty one) in all project

Although it's not explicitly said in the aforementioned manual, it seems to be the case and the Main Annotation Layer cannot be deleted. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days more and if there's no more input, I'll mark this answer as correct.
